# Facebook mobile redirects to app store and not the app

Tags: ios, facebook, native

I have a facebook app. On the mobile side I created an android app and a iOS app. SO if i click on the app it should redirect to the android/iOS app on the mobile or app store/ play store. On android it works fine but on iOS it never redirects to the app even if it's installed. It redirects to app store.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register a custom URL scheme in your app to redirect the user from one app to another on iOS.  In particular, Facebook will have you include your Facebook App ID as part of the URL scheme.

There is a nice tutorial here on creating custom URL schemes [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/).